# Neo4JClient: How to create relationships?

Tags: .net, neo4j

I saw a post with same title, but unfortunately couldn't find a soulution by looking at given examples

I have created the nodes the folowing way:

```
private static void createExampleNetwork(GraphClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            //CypherQuery cq = new CypherQuery();
            //string createNodeQuery = "CREATE (a {name : 'Andres'}) RETURN";
            //string response = cq.CreateRequest(createNodeQuery);

            var myNodeReferenceA = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "A" });
            var myNodeReferenceB = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "B" });
            var myNodeReferenceC = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "C" });
            var myNodeReferenceD = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "D" });
            var myNodeReferenceE = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "E" });
            var myNodeReferenceF = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "F" });
            var myNodeReferenceG = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "G" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I would like to create the following relationships:
A--B
A--C
A--D
C--D
B--G

but don't know how.

I've looked at examples
http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/src/4693da483a90/Test/RelationshipTests.cs
and
http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/src/4693da483a90/Test/ApiUsageIdeas.cs

but still don't know how the relationships are created.

I would be very thankful if anyone could give a useful example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution

```
private static void createExampleNetwork(GraphClient client)
    {
        try
        {

            var myNodeReferenceA = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "A" });
            var myNodeReferenceB = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "B" });
            var myNodeReferenceC = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "C" });
            var myNodeReferenceD = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "D" });
            var myNodeReferenceE = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "E" });
            var myNodeReferenceF = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "F" });
            var myNodeReferenceG = client.Create(new ExampleNode { Name = "G" });

            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceA, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceB));
            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceA, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceC));
            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceA, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceD));
            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceA, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceE));
            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceB, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceF));
            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceB, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceG));
            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceC, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceD));
            client.CreateRelationship(myNodeReferenceE, new NodeKnows(myNodeReferenceF));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

 public class NodeKnows :Relationship, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<ExampleNode>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<ExampleNode>
{
    public NodeKnows(NodeReference targetNode)
        : base(targetNode)
    {
    }

    public const string TypeKey = "KNOWS";
    public override string RelationshipTypeKey
    {
        get { return TypeKey; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I am using your example and wanted to find out the direct relationship at any level. I have posted a question too at SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252922/neo4jclient-how-to-view-the-relationship-direct-reportees#comment58229198_35252922    .Have   a look at the same at your spare time and any insight on the same will be valuable. Thanks