# Neo4JClient: How to view the relationship (Direct reportees)?

Tags: c#, neo4j

I have an example of creating relationship using [Neo4JClient: How to create relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961405/neo4jclient-how-to-create-relationships). How to view the relationship? I mean if I want to find how many nodes are directly connected to "A", how to do that?

### Update

After a little help from @manonthemat, I converted the cypher in C#

```
var record = client.Cypher
                    .Match("(A)-[r]->()")                   
                    .Return((A, r) => new
                    {
                        User = A.As<ExampleNode>(),
                        NumberOfFriends = r.Count()
                    }).Results;
```

Though I am able to get the direct count say 4 for A, I also want to get the names of those e.g. B,C,D,E. How to do so?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# in combination with Neo4j yet. To clarify, is this what you want in cypher? "A" being the node that you want its relationships counter: MATCH (A)-[r]->() RETURN COUNT(r);

Comment: @manonthemat, Though I am able to get the direct count say 4 for A, I also want to get the names of those e.g. B,C,D,E. How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you question to be "How do I determine the nodes which are connected to A?"

If you only want the nodes, the cypher query should look something like this:

```
Match A-[r:*]-(X)
Return distinct X
```

If you also want the relationships try this:

```
Match A-[r:*]-(X)
Return r, distinct X
```

Sometimes you may want to limit you search to only a certain kind of relationship, like "KNOWS".  In which case try this:

```
Match A-[r:KNOWS*]-(X)
Return r, distinct X
```

Comment: I tried like  var record1 = client.Cypher
                    .Match("(A)-[r:*]-(X)")
                    .ReturnDistinct<ExampleNode>("X").Results;  but error  SyntaxException: Invalid input '*': expected whitespace or a rel type name (line 1, column 14 (offset: 13))
"MATCH (A)-[r:*]-(X)
"
              ^